# Questions of BuildConfig

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm a newbie of Grails Plugin.

1. what's the difference between compile and build step?
2. where's the doc of plugins node,
3. what's the mean of export?
4. how can I force to auto install another plugin? If I install a plugin in my plugin, can It be used in the main app which installed my plugin?
5. what's the difference between config plugin in BuildConfig.groovy and application.properties?

Thanks

Comment: Newbie of Stackoverflow too - one question per question ...

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's the difference between compile and build step?

`grails compile` compiles the code, not sure what exactly you mean by "build step"

> where's the doc of plugins node

what do you mean by "plugins node"? The Grails plugins website is [here](http://grails.org/plugin/category/all).

> what's the mean of export?

no idea, where have you seen it used?

> how can I force to auto install another plugin?

you can unintall a plugin by running `grails uninstall-plugin <plugin name>`

> If I install a plugin in my plugin, can It be used in the main app which installed my plugin?

if app A depends on plugin P1 and P1 depends on plugin P2, then if P1 is installed in A, then P2 is normally also available to A. However, it is possible to exclude transitive plugin dependencies.

> what's the difference between config plugin in BuildConfig.groovy and application.properties?

They are both configuration files, but only `BuildConfig.groovy` should be edited - you can think of `application.properties` as being Grails` internal config file.

The only overlap between the two is that either may be used to specify plugin dependencies. In older versions of Grails, `application.properties` was the only place where plugin dependencies could be specified. In Grails 1.2.X (or thereabouts) `BuildConfig.groovy` was introduced as the preferred place to specify plugin dependencies, but `application.properties` is still supported.

Comment: what's the mean of export?  -- This is plugin, use to export your data in multiple types of file formats like pdf, excel and so on.